# Why does the order of these statements with 'and' change the output even with parentheses?

Tags: python

So I'm solving some code challenges for loops on Codecademy. And one particular problem is vexing me. Here is the setup as per Codecademy:

> Write a function called delete_starting_evens() that has a parameter named lst.
> The function should remove elements from the front of lst until the front of the list is not even. The function should then return lst.
> For example if lst started as [4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15], then delete_starting_evens(lst) should return [11, 12, 15].
> Make sure your function works even if every element in the list is even!

Now this code works fine and as I would expect:

```
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
  while (len(lst) > 0) and (lst[0] % 2 == 0):
    lst.pop(0)
  return lst

print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]))
print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10]))
```

while this code produces an error and I'm not sure why:

```
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
  while (lst[0] % 2 == 0) and (len(lst) > 0):
    lst.pop(0)
  return lst

print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]))
print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10]))`
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10]))
  File "script.py", line 3, in delete_starting_evens
    while (lst[0] % 2 == 0) and (len(lst) > 0):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: If you try and use `lst[0]` when `lst` is empty, you get an exception. That is why you should check `len(lst)` first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the short-circuit behaviour of `and`:

```
x and y
```

evaluates to the first false operand and does not evaluate any others because the result is clear already. So if `x` is false, `y` will not be evaluated, and any errors raised from evaluating `y` will hence be avoided. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

That's why you will often see:

```
if lst and lst[0]:  # if lst is empty, lst[0] will not be tried
    # ...
```

but not:

```
if lst[0] and lst:  # lst[0] raises error before lst is tested
    # ...
```

BTW, there is a library function for your exact use case, which is [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
from itertools import dropwhile

def delete_starting_evens(lst):
    return list(dropwhile(lambda x: not x%2, lst))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the last part of your answer means, but thanks!

Comment: It is just a short-hand for your code ;-) *"drop elements from lst while condition (not x%2) holds, keep rest"*

Answer (score 0):

It is because when the python interpreter evaluates your expression:

```
while (lst[0] % 2 == 0) and (len(lst) > 0):
```

It always checks the first statement first. In this case it is performing a check on lst[0] even when the list may be empty. The first chunk of code checks for `len(lst) > 0` first which is why there is no error.